# How to make a "title" cell in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to build a UITableView just like this one(please notice the grey cells(S,T,W) in that screenshot):
[image]

.
Is that two custom cells ? Or is there any other tip?

Comment: May I suggest that you read through the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451). If you are going to work with tables this is a must read document. It covers things like this and many other aspects of using tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a standard "header" for a `UITableView` with plain style.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 20) return @"S";

    if (section == 21) return @"T";

    if (section == 22) return @"W";

    return @"Undefined";
}
```

Comment: It answers my question above Wain answer so. I have to divide my UITableView into sections. Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI - this is a terrible way to setup a set of alphabetized section headers. Using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is a much better way for the section headers and the indexes down the side. At a minimum, use an array of titles. Or at least use a `switch` statement instead of a whole set of `if` statements.

Comment: @rmaddy of course, I'm not showing the proper implementation to setup the alphabetized headers. Just some quick sample code in reference to the OP question to give him an idea.

Comment: @PeterWarbo Perhaps but keep in mind that newbies tend to copy and don't know enough to realize what you posted is far, far from ideal. If you post code, it's best to post reasonable code. Or in a case like this, simply point the person to the proper method like in Wain's answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Those rows are section headers. See `titleForHeaderInSection` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: So if I have 2 sections I'll have 2 titles? I thought about a custom cell that if I even have one section I can build more than one titles. Thank you for your answer, now I know how to make this.